# How to configure Spring Webflow

Tags: spring-webflow

I am setting up the environment. I'm getting an error whenever I am adding my XML bean files to Spring elements:

> Cannot Locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [flow:executor]

My flow is:

```xml
<webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" >
        <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
            <webflow:listener ref="jpaFlowExecutionListener" />
            <webflow:listener ref="facesContextListener" />
        </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
    </webflow:flow-executor>
```

And my default configurations are:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.4.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces.xsd">
```

Comment: Is this really the code you're running? The error says "`flow:executor`" but you have "`webflow:flow-executor`"

Comment: yes that is the error I am having, it appeared after adding the webflow-config.xml file in spring elements